# iOS UI/UX advice needed regarding dynamically hide and show fields

Tags: ios, user-interface

I have a scenario similar to the Web questionnaire forms, say I have 3 questions on the form:

A
B
C

B only appears when I answer yes to question A, C only appears when I answer yes to question B.

Is there any guideline on how to achieve this sort of UI on iOS? Or we just simply follow the Web way of doing it for iOS? As I haven't seen any of these samples on iOS apps.

Thanks and regards

Comment: This might be more appropriate at http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One relatively easy way to do this is in a UITableView and via the UITableViewController. As the user answers each questions the next can be revealed by adding a row. Code to add a row is as follows and should be placed in a tableViewController.

```
-(void)showNextRow:(int)row inSection:(int)section
{
    NSArray *newRowIndexPath = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];

    UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)self.view;
    [tv beginUpdates];
    [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths: newRowIndexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tv endUpdates];
}
```

You will need a data model that keeps track of all the questions and the current question being answered and will have to use that to keep the following function up to date

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

And to populate your UITableViewCells